# Texture Coordinate + Mapping Node

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

Ok, i'm really having a hard time understanding these 2 nodes.
I watched several videos (tried to find some reference in the docs) but many many grey areas are left.
Sometimes, i get the feeling that i got it, but then, another test just gets me confused again...

It just doesn't want to click with me...

After this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0), i think i got the idea about how the generated and object texture coordinates system work.
I imagine the texture coordinates as an array of points in 3D Space. For each of these points, following a projection rule (Z-axe from top to down; saw this in the video, found it nowhere in the docs), a pixel of a texture-image is found and applied at this coordinate.

Ok, but when we use the mapping node to add an X=0.30m to the coordinates, what is the thing that is moving ?

- Is it the object local axes (local space) ?
- Is it the objects bounding box ?
- Is it the axes (U, V) of the texture image ? (i would say it is this one, but not sure)

By the way, there are 2 sets of coordinates, the "Texture Coordinates" (position of the points of a mesh, from an origin, in 3D space, X-Y-Z) and the pixels coordinates (position of a pixel in a texture image, U-V)

How should i think this through ?

Comment: it looks like it's using the object's origin as the center point to project the image texture or the procedural texture, not sure about your question though